# tsserver wont import <Text> or <Map> component in javascript

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, jsx, neovim

When I try to add a react component that also matches the default libraries, instead of getting an error along the lines of "missing import" the LSP thinks I want to use the javascript `new Text(...)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/Text instead of the `react-native` `<Text/>` component.
[image: "map" cannot be used as a JSX component]

If I am currently typing it gets it right which is strange. As you can see `LSP -> react-native` shows up as expected.

[image: typing fixes it]

I can somewhat fix this problem by adding `"noLib": true` to my `jsconfig.json` but that isnt ideal because anytime I actually want to use something for the standard library I get an error (for example `new Date(...)` in a function). But this will suggest the correct text.
[image: correctly identifies the issue]

Here is my jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "checkJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noLib": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
  },
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "build",
    ".vscode",
    "coverage",
    ".npm",
    ".yarn"
  ],
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true,
    "include": [
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "jest",
      "testing-library__jest-dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Note instead of `.jsx` file endings, I use `.js` this is a requirement that I cannot change. Also I have tried changing them and the same behavior is seen.

Also obviously if I add `import {Text} from 'react-native'` at the top of my file it fixes the problem as well. But that misses the entire point of my LSP.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131840 pointed out that eslint lsp clears the suggestions. When I disabled it it works perfectly fine.